# ElasticsearchDSL builder how to create SHOULD NOT query

Tags: php, elasticsearch, dsl, ongr

Using the php dsl builder, I'm trying to create a `SHOULD NOT` query. Using the json query syntax you can nest a `MUST_NOT` within a `SHOULD` bool to create one.

**Example**

```
{"bool": {"should": { "bool": {"must_not": {"match": {"thing": "thingy"}}}}}}
```

Reading through the ongr documentation it isn't clear how to achieve the same the result since the 5.0 update release. I've tried the following:

```
$search = new Search();
$query = new MatchQuery('thing', 'thingy');
$search->addQuery($query, BoolQuery::MUST_NOT);
$search->addPostFilter(BoolQuery::SHOULD);
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to nest the bool queries, you need to use bool queries :) The example you provided can be achieved with this code snippet:

```
$search = new Search();
$outerBoolQuery = new BoolQuery();
$innerBoolQuery = new BoolQuery();
$innerBoolQuery->add(new MatchQuery('thing', 'thingy'), BoolQuery::MUST_NOT);
$outerBoolQuery->add($innerBoolQuery, BoolQuery::SHOULD);
```